# I'm currently working on an online store website and I have a problem with updating the cart

Tags: django

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

from .cart import Cart

from product.models import Product

def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.add(product_id)

    return render(request, 'cart/partials/menu_cart.html')

def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html')

def update_cart(request, product_id, action):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if action == 'increment':
         cart.add(product_id, 1, True)
    else:
         cart.add(product_id, -1, True)

    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    quantity = cart.get_item(product_id)

    if quantity:
         quantity = quantity['quantity']

         item = {
             'product': {
                 'id': product.id,
                 'name': product.name,
                 'image': product.image,
                 'get_thumbnail': product.get_thumbnail(),
                 'price': product.price,
             },
             'total_price': (quantity * product.price) / 100,
             'quantity': quantity,
         }
     else:
         item = None

     response = render(request, 'cart/partials/cart_item.html', {'item': item})
     response['HX-Trigger'] = 'update-menu-cart'

     return response

 @login_required
 def checkout(request):
     return render(request, 'cart/checkout.html')

 def hx_menu_cart(request):
     return render(request, 'cart/partials/menu_cart.html')

 def hx_cart_total(request):
     return render(request, 'cart/partials/cart_total.html')
```

cart.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Shopping cart | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto flex flex-wrap item-start py-6 px-6 xl:px-0">
  <div class="products w-full lg:w-3/4">
    {% for item in cart %}
      {% include 'cart/partials/cart_item.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="summary w-full md:w-1/4 p-6 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl mt-3">
    <h2 class="uppercase text-lg mb-5">Summary</h2>
    <div class="mb-6 flex justify-between">
      <span class="font-semibold">Total</span>
      <span
        hx-get="{% url 'hx_cart_total' %}"
        hx-trigger="update-menu-cart from:body"
        hx-swap="innerHTML">
        {% include 'cart/partials/cart_total.html' %}
      </span>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'checkout' %}" class="inline block px-8 py-4 rounded-xl bg-cyan-400 hover:bg-cyan-500 text-white">Checkout</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

partials/cart_item.html:

```
{% if item %}
    <div class="product mb-6 flex pr-6" id="cart-item-{{ item.product.id }}">
        <a href="{% url 'product' item.product.slug %}" class="w-1/4">
            <img class="hover:shadow-lg rounded-xl" src="{{ item.product.get_thumbnail }}">
        </a>

        <div class="w-3/4 pl-6">
            <div class="flex justify-between">
                <a href="{% url 'product' item.product.slug %}" class="text-lg">{{ item.product.name }}</a>

                <span class="mb-6 pt-1 text-gray-400">${{ item.total_price }}</span>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="quantity mt-6 flex items-center space-x-4">
                <a
                    class="p-3 bg-gray-100"
                    hx-get="{% url 'update_cart' item.product.id 'decrement' %}"
                    hx-target="#cart-item-{{ item.product.id }}"
                    hx-swap="outerHTML"
                >
                    -
                </a>
                <span>{{ item.quantity }}</span>
                <a
                    class="p-3 bg-gray-100"
                    hx-get="{% url 'update_cart' item.product.id 'increment' %}"
                    hx-target="#cart-item-{{ item.product.id }}"
                    hx-swap="outerHTML"
                >
                    +
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

error:

```
Internal Server Error: /cart/update_cart/3/increment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\Desktop\Hitech website\hitech\cart\views.py", line 45, in update_cart
    response = render(request, 'cart/partials/cart_item.html', {'item': item})
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render

    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ALECO TAFO\envs\HitechEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'product' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
[02/Aug/2022 01:01:36] "GET /cart/update_cart/3/increment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 135835
```

I don't have any problems with the decrementing function, it works perfectly fine, but i can't increment the product (the number of products in the cart isn't modifying, nor the price).
I will also show you the urls.py files because of that "1 pattern(s) tried" error, maybe it will help you.

cart/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from cart.views import add_to_cart, cart, checkout, hx_menu_cart, update_cart, hx_cart_total

urlpatterns = [
    path('', cart, name = 'cart'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name = 'checkout'),
    path('add_to_cart/<int:product_id>/', add_to_cart, name = 'add_to_cart'),
    path('update_cart/<int:product_id>/<str:action>/', update_cart, name = 'update_cart'),
    path('hx_menu_cart/', hx_menu_cart, name = 'hx_menu_cart'),
    path('hx_cart_total/', hx_cart_total, name = 'hx_cart_total'),
]
```

main/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.urls import path

from main.views import frontpage, shop, signup, account, edit_account
from product.views import product

urlpatterns = [
    path('', frontpage, name = 'frontpage'),
    path('signup/', signup, name = 'signup'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html'), name = 'login'),
    path('account/', account, name = 'account'),
    path('account/edit', edit_account, name = 'edit_account'),
    path('shop/', shop, name = 'shop'),
    path('shop/<slug:slug>/', product, name = 'product'),
]
```

Comment: Look at the error.. it's complaining that it can't find a reverse match for a url named "product" with argument "".  Looking at your urls.conf I see that the url "product" requires a slug, which "" is not... so you have got to figure out why `item.product.slug` in your template has a value of "" rather than a legit slug that's going to identify the product.

Comment: item.product.slug it is used for when the client wants to open the product's page by clicking the image from the cart, and it is working perfectly fine. The url named "product" also works perfectly fine. Maybe the mistake is somewhere else ...

Comment: Maybe, or maybe it isn't.  Check your data.. because that's what the traceback text is telling you.

Comment: i managed to solve the problem, so if there is anyone having a similar question, but also in particular for @little_birdie, i am going to break it down here: the mistake was indeed in the sequence  `{% url 'product' item.product.slug %}` because it couldn't find the correct url and this is why the incrementing function didn't work properly. This is why removing the sequence mentioned above solved the problem. Also, now i couldn't access the product.html page via clicking the product image in the cart, so i changed that sequence with `{% url 'product' item.product.name|slugify %}` and all works